# Horizontal scroll bar instead of responsive

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've got my CSS and HTML code where I have a few problems. Basically, I'm looking to not have a responsive design, but instead have the page scroll horizontally when the browser window is resized.

Here's my website fastreturn.net
If you have a wide screen and resolution, it looks fine. However, when you resize it, it breaks.

Here's a screenshot of what it's supposed to look like and what happens when I resize.

What it's supposed to look like:
http://puu.sh/41NDz/e060ff2757.png

And here is what it looks like once the browser is resized:
http://puu.sh/41NFT/743ce762c2.png

Here's the CSS:
http:// pastebin.com/Lxm199aZ

I'd like a horizontal scroll bar to just show up and let people scroll horizontally when the browser is resized, instead of it all breaking.

Anyone got any advice?

Comment: can you post the css or a fiddle

Comment: You should wrap all content in a container with a `min-width` and center that container(s). Provide code for better help

Answer (score -1):

You can use min-width[1] property to define minimum width for your page / container.
[1] http://goo.gl/EHEv6l